# JSDoc - specifying mandatory parameter syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, doxygen, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am using @JSDoc to create documentation for my javascript library. I know how to indicate optional parameter. like below

```
/*
 * @param {string} [somebody] - Somebody's name.
 */
function sayHello(somebody) {
    if (!somebody) {
        somebody = 'John Doe';
    }
    alert('Hello ' + somebody);
}
```

But I would like to indicate some parameters in my API are mandatory. How to indicate it using JSDOC.
I don't find any from 
[JSDoc tags-param](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you mark a parameter as optional, then the parameter is considered mandatory. There's nothing additional you need to do. To make your `somebody` parameter mandatory you'd just remove the brackets:

```
@param {string} somebody - Somebody's name.
```

Comment: @Luis how do we mark one of the parameters as mandatory. Let's say there are opt1 and opt2. One of them is must.